# Quickly shut down a remote server with batch file

Tags: batch-file, command, remote-access, remote-server

I know how to use a shut down command (shutdown -r -f -f 0) to shut down a computer but I am trying to create a batch file to shut down remotely a computer/server in case of emergency.

Thanks.
Amir

Comment: You can usually help yourself by reading the help file for the command you are trying to use.  Type shutdown /? at a cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2):

shutdown with "/m" parameter
shutdown.exe /m \\hostname -s -t 0

or 
wmic.exe OS Where Primary=TRUE Call Win32Shutdown 1

or psshutdown.exe from Sysinternals

or psexec.exe \\hostname -u [user] -p [password] -accepteula shutdown.exe -s -t 0

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psshutdown.aspx